Understanding normal reactions on a ring
I need to find all the normal reactions and the frictional forces acting on the ring to keep it in a state of equilibrium.
It's given that a force $\vec{P}$ is being applied by a finger on a ring that sits on a ground, as show in the image on the left.
My confusion starts with normal reactions acting on the ring and the finger: If the finger applies a force $\vec P$ there must also be normal reactions acting, because there is a contact:

$\vec N_{\text{ring}}$ is the normal reaction on the ring applied by the finger.
$\vec N_{\text{finger}}$ is the normal reaction on the finger applied by the ring.
$\vec f_{\text{ring}}$ is the static frictional force acting on the ring.
$\vec N_{\text{ground}}$ is the normal reaction on the ring by the ground.
$\vec f_{\text{ground}}$ is the static friction force on the ring by the ground.

If I just look at the forces in the $y$ direction i.e. $\vec N_{\text{ring}}, \vec N_{\text{finger}}, \vec P$, then to maintain equilibrium the following must be true
$$ \vec P + \vec N_{\text{ring}} + \vec N_{\text{finger}} ~=~ 0 $$
$$ \vec P + \vec N_{\text{ring}} ~=~ -\vec N_{\text{finger}}$$
The equation $\vec P + \vec N_{\text{ring}} = -\vec N_{\text{finger}}$ confuses me because $\vec N_{\text{ring}}$ and $\vec N_{\text{finger}}$ are action reaction pairs so they must have the same magnitude because of Newtons $3^{rd}$ law. Which means to satisfy the above equation $\vec P$ must be $0$, which is not true in the question asked, $\vec P$ has a force.


$P$ and $N_{\text{ring}}$ are the same force.

Thank you. That helped. I guess I still need to read more because I still don't intuitively get why $P$ and $N_{ring}$ are the same force. If there was a box on a surface, the weight $W$ of the box and $N_{box}$ would not be the same, then why would $P$ and $N_{ring}$ here be the same .

In your list and on your diagram you need to have forces that are acting on the ring.

$\vec N_{\text{ring}}$ is the normal reaction on the ring applied by the finger $\bf =$ force on the ring due to the finger, $\vec P$ .
$\vec N_{\text{finger}}$ is the normal reaction on the finger applied by the ring.
$\vec f_{\text{ring}}$ is the static frictional force acting on the ring.
$\vec N_{\text{ground}}$ is the normal reaction on the ring by the ground.
$\vec f_{\text{ground}}$ is the static friction force on the ring by the ground.


Thank you. Yep you are right. In my calculations, I did account for the forces that are just acting on the ring.
